# Cannot access App_Code logic from Controller

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm just starting with my first ASP.Net WebApi 2 project.  I have a file like this:

**/AppCode/Remits.vb**

```
Public Class Remits
    Public Shared Function GetBoolean(id As Integer, id2 As Integer) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

This function will need to be called from all my controllers.  The function checks that the two ID parameters are valid (done using some extensive database logic which is removed for brevity).

**/Controllers/TestController.vb**

```
Namespace Controllers

    Public Class TestController
        Inherits ApiController

        <Route("Test/{id}")>
        Public Function [Get](id As Int32) As IHttpActionResult
            Dim b As Boolean = myNs.Remits.GetBoolean(123, 456) ' <-- error (see below)
            Return Ok(b)
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

This won't even compile, with the error

> 'myNs' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

Why is the namespace and/or class not accessible from within a controller?  Or, what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Anything inside **App_Code** is not recognised by files in the former directories.  I've updated the question to reflect this.  Here is a (tiny) sample project highlighting the problem.
http://1drv.ms/1kqjwTX

Comment: Are both these namespaces within the same parent Namespace?  Are you using any Imports statements anywhere?  And if not, have you tried them?  Use the Object Browser to have a look over the structure of your Namespaces.

Comment: `MyNs` is not listed when using `Imports` statements either.  Even if I type `Dim b as Boolean = RootNamespace.` it *still* does not list `MyNS` in intellisense

Comment: I vaguely remember having similar problems the first time I used ASP.NET... lol.  Sorry, but I'm not going to be much help!  Tried the Object Browser?

Comment: Object browser was helpful thanks.  Please see updated information

Comment: Looking at one of my own web projects... it seems namespaces are automatically created for master pages and global script (.asax).  Basically, what I appear to have done (several years ago) is not use any namespaces at all...

Comment: Don't put the code in the App_Code folder.  That folder is for web site projects only.  Rename that folder to include it in your project.

Comment: Tried that thanks but no joy.  Please see the attached file highlighting the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add classes to App_Code it is set to build action "Content".  You need to change this to "Compile".

So:

1. Do not use App_Code, rename that folder
2. Change any class files to "Compile" build action.

For #2.  Select the file in Solution Explorer and in the properties window (if you don't have this open by default right click the file and choose properties) there is an option called Build Action.  Change that to Compile.

Comment: Edited my answer to give more info.

Comment: Still doing this in VS2019. ...and this is totally lame on the part of MSFT.